# Android + Wowza + RTSP. play well, but cannot control MediaController

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, wowza

This is the code I wrote.

It works well.

```
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.sk_opening_video);
_mc = new MediaController(this);
_videoView.setMediaController(_mc);
_videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.0.7:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4"));
_videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.start();
    }
});
```

But the problem is that I cannot play back or forward, even move progress bar point; It just won't move.

So if I play the video once, I have no any option but to watch the whole video.

All I can do is to pause the video and play.

What is the problem??????!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wowza delivers the video streams based on chunks and it is not using progressive download method to buffer, seek, etc.,

If you want an option with seeking forward, backward, play, pause you should configure [Wowza NDVR](http://www.wowza.com/addons/wowza-ndvr-addon) application. Wowza NDVR allows you to do all the operations

Here is the Wowza NDVR documentation : http://www.wowza.com/resources/WowzanDVRAddOn_UsersGuide-3.5.0.pdf